# How to correctly reference external definition classes in specflow

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mstest, specflow

I've looked through the specflow documentation as well as several posts online (some on here too) about how to use external class libraries in my specflow project. And I've tried to use the suggestions but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I'm trying to reference an external class in an external project to be "called" by my specflow feature.

I understand my configuration needs to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow"     type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
    <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="UtilityClasses"/>
    </stepAssemblies>
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

So I have my separate project called UtilityClasses with a csharp file in there called Admin_Subtests.cs

However even after adding the step assembly to the config, the feature file won't seem to pick up the step, even after being rebuilt.

The csharp file contains the following (amongst other things):

```
namespace SeleniumDPS
{
    [Binding]
    public class Admin_Subtests
    {

    [When(@"I click Register")]
    [Given(@"I click Register")]
    public static void Subtest_Navigation_Registration()
    {
        try
        {
            Admin_Navigation.Registration.Click();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { WebDriver.CatchNTrash(ex); }
        //Logging for subtest
        WebDriver.TestLog().LogSubTest(WebDriver.TestLog().GetTestResult(), "I click Register");
    }

    etc
```

This is my feature file:

```
Scenario: LPSS_AdminRegistration_PrivateLandlord
     Given I click Register
```

And for some reason it just doesn't pick it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated even if its a silly mistake on my behalf. I've been looking at it for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it appears that I did the referencing correctly. Bascially if I build and run it the test passes.

So what I did was restart VS2013 Ultimate and it now shows as fine.

But if I make changes in the spec flow feature file it flags it as red again, as if the methods its trying to call dont exist. But again if I build and run the test it will work. I'm assuming this is a bug with specflow.